# Defining a Macro in C with a set of operators

Tags: c, macros

I´m relatively new in programming and I was trying to define a macro called OPERATORS in the following way:

```
#define OPERATORS {'+', '-','*', '/', '%', '^'}
```

This, with the purpose of making the following programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define OPERATORS {'+', '-','*', '/', '%', '^'}

int isOperator (char c) {
    if(c!=OPERATORS)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    printf("%d", isOperator('+'));
    printf("%d", isOperator('j'));
    return 0;
}
```

To know, whether the character c is, or not, an operator.
But I had problems with the compiler which I´m sure to be related with the declaration of the macro. So my question is:

**How can I define a macro with a set of operators and how should I use  it?? ´Cause I´m almost sure that to compare a variable with the macro, it should be done in a different way**
Sorry for my ignorance and thank you so much!!!

Comment: Don't use a macro for this.

Comment: A macro is just a text replacement. What you have here `if(c!=OPERATORS)` translates to `if(c!={'+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '^'}` which doesn't compile. I'm not sure a macro/text replacement is what you want. You could just an actual array and check if c matches any of the values of the array

Comment: This isn't how C works at all. Why do you need a macro anyway? How about `return strchr("+-*/%^", c) != NULL;` instead?

Comment: You need a function like `strchr()` not a macro.

Comment: Thank you all!! Yeah, I was confused when our professor told us to make it this way!! Of course it is a billion times easier to make it with an array. Guess I´m gonna have to ask him. Thanks!!

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Sorry my mistake. I meant to say [`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros do only textual substituation, so your code is actually equivalent to this:

```
int isOperator (char c) {
    if (c != {'+', '-','*', '/', '%', '^'})
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

which is invalid C code, you cannot compare a `char` to an array of chars which doesn't make sense anyway.

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isOperator(char c) {
  static char operators[] = { '+', '-','*', '/', '%', '^' };
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof operators; i++)
    if (c == operators[i])
      return 1;

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", isOperator('+'));
  printf("%d\n", isOperator('j'));
  return 0;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
...
#include <string.h>
...
int isOperator(char c) {
  char operators[] = "+-*/%^";
  return strchr(operators, c) != NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! As I thought a macro here is useless!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

Yuo can also use lookup table

```
#include <stdint.h>

const int type[256] = {['%'] = 1, ['+'] = 1, ['-'] = 1, ['/'] = 1, ['*'] = 1, ['^'] = 1, ['!'] = 1, 
                       ['0'] = 2, ['1'] = 2, ['2'] = 2, ['3'] = 2, ['4'] = 2, ['5'] = 2, ['6'] = 2, ['7'] = 2, ['8'] = 2, ['9'] = 2,
};

int myisoperator(int c)
{
    return type[c] == 1;
}

int myisdigit(int c)
{
    return type[c] == 2;
}
```

Comment: consider using `UCHAR_MAX` for the size of the array for better portability.

Comment: If your `c` argument is outside of the range of 0 to 255, you'll have an invalid memory access (potentially a segmentation fault, but also possibly read adjacent memory structures.) I feel like a range check should be needed at least as assertions in the code.

Comment: @filbranden `strlen` the same. It is up to programmer to do not. In demo code it does not make any sense to check all possible problems.

Comment: Changing the argument type to `unsigned char` (OP is using a `char` in their attempt anyways) and using `UCHAR_MAX` for the length of the array should handle all of those bounds issues, I believe, and is simple enough to implement.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons think why char operations in the standard library take int as a char parameters ...

Comment: There's no benefit in taking an `int` if you aren't going to handle any cases where anything larger than an 8-bit value is used.

Comment: @P__J__ Because they properly handle `-1` (`EOF`).